# Subscribe в subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

У меня есть behaviorSubject, в котором хранится текущий юзер. Соответственно юзеру не получается вытащить заказы:

```
        // behaviorSubject
        this.auth.currUser.subscribe(x => console.log('currUser', x)); 
    
        // как-то сюда нужно получить значение с Observable бихевиор сабджекта
        this.getNewOrders(currUser._id) 
        .subscribe(
          orders => {
            console.log('orders',orders);
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        )
    
        // http request:
        getNewOrders(): Observable {
          return this.http.get(`${this.URL}/bookings_new/${currUser._id}`);
        }
```

В какую сторону копать? CombineLatest не то, вроде как можно сделать с помощью flatMap, но не понимаю как именно это работает.

Comment: `this.auth.currUser.pipe( mergeMap(currUser => this.getNewOrders(currUser._id)) ).subscribe(orders => console.log(orders))`

Comment: @overthesanity, спасибо большое, работает!)

Comment: @overthesanity, а можно еще вопрос? Если мне нужно проверять наличие новых заказов каждые скажем 10сек? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gkjegw

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xaou9o

Comment: @overthesanity, спасибо огромное-огромное!)))))